# How to save the preferences in Local Storage (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I got 2 radio buttons and each one have a function (change the weather from celsius to fahrenheit)
The wearher data is from an API.

```
        <p>
          <label>
            Celsius
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="weather"
              value="celsius"
              class="celsius"
              onclick="weatherC()"
            />
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            Fahrenheit
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="weather"
              value="fahrenheit"
              class="fahrenheit"
              onclick="weatherF()"
            />
          </label>
        </p>
```

Those are the functions in JavaScript:

```
  function weatherC() {
    fetch("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Azuga&units=metric&appid=cbf24ef0d0428af6ca69c8320756cbf5")
    .then(handleResponse)
    .then((data) => {
      const maxTemp = document.querySelector(".max-temp");
      maxTemp.innerText = Math.ceil(data.main["temp_max"]) + "\u2103";

      const minTemp = document.querySelector(".min-temp");
      minTemp.innerText = Math.ceil(data.main["temp_min"]) + "\u2103";

      const currentTemp = document.querySelector(".current-temp");
      currentTemp.innerText = Math.ceil(data.main["temp"]) + "\u2103";

      const feelsLike = document.querySelector(".feels-like");
      feelsLike.innerText = Math.ceil(data.main["feels_like"]) + "\u2103";

      const city = document.querySelector(".city");
      city.innerText = data["name"];

      const statusIcon = document.querySelector(".iconClass");
      const iconFromApi = data.weather[0].icon;
      const icon = `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${iconFromApi}@2x.png`;
      statusIcon.innerHTML = `<img src="${icon}">`;
    });
  }
  function weatherF() {
    fetch("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Azuga&units=fehrenheit&appid=cbf24ef0d0428af6ca69c8320756cbf5")
    .then(handleResponse)
    .then((data) => {
      const maxTemp = document.querySelector(".max-temp");
      maxTemp.innerText = Math.ceil(data.main["temp_max"]) + "\u2109";

      const minTemp = document.querySelector(".min-temp");
      minTemp.innerText = Math.ceil(data.main["temp_min"]) + "\u2109";

      const currentTemp = document.querySelector(".current-temp");
      currentTemp.innerText = Math.ceil(data.main["temp"]) + "\u2109";

      const feelsLike = document.querySelector(".feels-like");
      feelsLike.innerText = Math.ceil(data.main["feels_like"]) + "\u2109";

      const city = document.querySelector(".city");
      city.innerText = data["name"];

      const statusIcon = document.querySelector(".iconClass");
      const iconFromApi = data.weather[0].icon;
      const icon = `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${iconFromApi}@2x.png`;
      statusIcon.innerHTML = `<img src="${icon}">`;
    });
  }

  weatherC();
```

how can i make it that when i refresh the page the selected radio button to remain the same?(I m new to js so an example would be awesome :D)

Comment: You should be able to figure it out yourself using [MDN's documentation on the localStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Do you want to save it permanently or only as long as the browser is open?

Answer (score 0):

In the weatherF and the weatherC functions you need to put in a localStorage.setItem call

And then in the page load you need to do a check if localStorage.getItem() return null

If local storage is new to you set up a few small apps where you test out the locaStorage.setItem(key, value) and localStorage.getItem(key)

If you set up the localStorage functions and you can’t get it to work post again and can take a look at it. You really should do a bit more of the code though before positing.

Comment: Well i added 
`  localStorage.setItem("item1", "celsius");`
`  let item = localStorage.getItem("item1");`
`  console.log(item);`
and when i press the button i got the right key